# Set Connection Id Exception Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a wpf app. I added an Integer updown by referencing to Xceed.wpf.toolkit as per the following code:

```
 <Page x:Class="AutomateClick.Business_Rule"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:wpfx="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
          d:DesignHeight="470" d:DesignWidth="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
           Title="Business_Rule">            
                <StackPanel x:Name="Rec_sel" Height="75" Margin="-270,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible">
                    <TextBlock Text="Day" Margin="-210,15,0,0" Height="22" Width="55" TextAlignment="Right" Name="Rec_Param" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="mon_sel1" IsChecked="True" Margin="5,-20,0,0" Visibility="Visible" Checked="mon_sel1_Click"/>
                    <wpfx:IntegerUpDown Name="input_freq" IsEnabled="True" Height="24" Margin="-90,-26,0,0" Width="50" AllowTextInput="False" Value="1" Increment="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="of every month" Margin="60,-22,0,0" Height="22" Width="90" TextAlignment="Left" Name="input_freq_based_text" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="mon_sel2" IsChecked="False" Margin="6,15,0,0" Visibility="Visible" Checked="mon_sel1_Click" />
                    <TextBlock Text="On" Margin="-105,-15,0,0" Height="22" Width="90" TextAlignment="Left" Name="mon_tb" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <ComboBox Name="mon_sel_cb_1" Width="80" Margin="-70,-25,0,0" Height="22">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="First"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Second"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Third"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Fourth"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Last"></ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <ComboBox Name="mon_sel_cb_2" Width="95" Margin="110,-25,0,0" Height="22">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Day"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Sunday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Monday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Tuesday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Wednesday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Thursday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Friday"></ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Saturday"></ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>         
    </Page>
```

When I run my code in the Visual studio it does not give me any exception and works fine. But when I run the exe of the Published app it gives me an exception on Line number 6 and Line position 7 (xmlns:wpfx="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit").
Please help!

Comment: Hi, what is the exception? And stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're missing the DLL of the toolkit in your application directory.

Please make sure it's there.

One of the ways to automatically copy it, is to make sure `Copy Local` is set to `True`. You can find it at the properties of the reference or other file.

[image]

Comment: You were right I maually copied the dll with exe and it runs fine. Thank You so much! Is there a way to prevent this type of situation because I just want to give end user the exe. Is there someway it gets placed there automatically?

Comment: @DhimanshuJassal: sorry, I was offline for a while: I added a method. Depending on your studio version or how you referenced the assembly, it might differ a bit.